# Windows 10 IoT core Device Portal does not show LoggingChannel events

Tags: logging, uwp, raspberry-pi, etw, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to log the information using Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics.LoggingChannel class, in my UWP headless app that runs on a Raspberry Pi.

I don't see any errors while running the application, but I cannot see any events in Device portal-ETW viewer.
I have enabled “Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-LoggingChannel” level 5.

Below is the code snippet from my application.

```
 Using Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics;
    LoggingChannel loggingChannel = new LoggingChannel("test provider", null);
    loggingChannel.LogMessage("Process started",LoggingLevel.Information);
```

Please note that I can see the events for other providers like Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LoggingChannel registered in your code is not for Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-LoggingChannel but for your custom channel. You can see the events via enabling the custom provider with GUID. For example, i run the [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Logging) on my Raspberry Pi 3, i can see the events in Device Portal.Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-LoggingChannel is system registered provider.
[image]